How to solve the following systems of equations: $3x^{2}+y=7$ and $4y^{2}-x=5$
How to solve the system of equations :
$3x^{2}+y=7$ ; $4y^{2}-x=5$

From desmos it is very much clear to me that the given system of equations will have $4$ solutions.
Now
I am trying to solve the equation by elimination method.
That is $3x^{2}+y=7$ and $4y^{2}-x=5$ are the given equations.
Now from the $1^{st}$ equation, $y=7-3x^{2}$.
Therefore we can say that $y^{2}=(7-3x^{2})^{2}$
That is we can say that $$4(7-3x^{2})^{2}-x=5$$ from the $2^{nd}$ equation.
$$\implies 4(9x^{4}-42x^{2}+49)-x=5$$
$$\implies 36x^{4}-168x^{2}-x+196=5$$
$$\implies 36x^{4}-168x^{2}-x+191=0$$
Now I am unable to find the values of $x$. Please help me out with the values of $x$.

Your attempts look ok at first sight, and you end up with a four-degree equation, which is extremely hard to solve. Generally, when students get such an equation, there always are some "simple" solutions like $x=-1, 0, 1, ...$, which is clearly not the case here. This gives me the impression that it's not a question you received from your teacher, but one you invented yourself in order to train yourself. Am I right? Or to be shorter: where do you get this question from?

$\text{Where did you find this question?}$

This is a quartic equation. Generally these are very tricky to solve analytically. In particular you have a depressed quartic, which can be solveable but very difficult.

Yes you are right. @Dominique. I want to study mathematics in depth. I don't like studying just only the syllabus.

@Gwen, but desmos is giving real values of $x, y$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=solve+3Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2By%3D7+and+4Power%5By%2C2%5D-x%3D5

Will the values of $x,y$ be real or imaginary ?

@Delhi: the results are real, as you can see in your graph. The whole issue here is the question: are you required to be able to solve four-degree questions? In case not, there's no problem admitting that you can't solve this question in an analytical way.

Cardano's Methods
Starting from $36x^{4}-168x^{2}-x+191=0$:
$$\begin{align}
36x^{4}-168x^{2}+191&=x
\end{align}$$
Add just the right $x^2$ and constant terms so that both sides become a perfect square. Not knowing what values of $a$ and $b$ to use yet, add $ax^2+b$ to each side:
$$\begin{align}
36x^{4}+(a-168)x^{2}+(191+b)&=ax^2+x+b
\end{align}$$
For the right side to be a perfect square, you need its discriminant to be $0$. And $1-4ab=0\implies b=\frac{1}{4a}$. So now:
$$\begin{align}
36x^{4}+(a-168)x^{2}+\left(191+\frac{1}{4a}\right)&=ax^2+x+\frac{1}{4a}\\
144ax^{4}+4a(a-168)x^{2}+\left(764a+1\right)&=4a^2x^2+4ax+1\\
144ax^{4}+4a(a-168)x^{2}+\left(764a+1\right)&=(2ax+1)^2
\end{align}$$
For the left side to be a perfect square, we need its discriminant to be $0$
$$\begin{align}
16a^2(a-168)^2-4(144a)(764a+1)&=0&&(16a\neq0)\\
a(a-168)^2-36(764a+1)&=0\\
a^3-336a^2+720a-36&=0
\end{align}$$
This is a cubic equation in $a$, so it can be solved to find a real number $a$ that works for our purposes. That is a side quest that I will complete below. Pretend we did that and now know an actual expression for $a$.
$$\begin{align}
144ax^{4}+4a(a-168)x^{2}+\left(764a+1\right)&=(2ax+1)^2\\
144a^2x^{4}+4a^2(a-168)x^{2}+a\left(764a+1\right)&=(2ax+1)^2\\
\text{...because $a$ makes the above a perfect square...}\\
\left(12ax^2+\frac16a(a-168)\right)^2&=(2ax+1)^2\\
12ax^2+\frac16a(a-168)&=\pm(2ax+1)\\
72ax^2+a(a-168)&=\pm6(2ax+1)
\end{align}$$
Now you would just have two (one for the $+$, one for the $-$) quadratic equations to solve (with solutions in terms of that number $a$). You would have the four $x$-values.
Side Quest to find $a$
We need to solve $a^3-336a^2+720a-36=0$. We can eliminate the quadratic term by introducing variable $c$, with $a=c+112$:
$$\begin{align}
(c+112)^3-336(c+112)^2+720(c+112)-36&=0\\
c^3-36912c-2729252&=0
\end{align}$$
Now we break $c$ up into the sum of two numbers that we don't know for now:
$$\begin{align}
(p+q)^3-36912(p+q)-2729252&=0\\
p^3+q^3+3(pq-12304)(p+q)-2729252&=0
\end{align}$$
We need $p+q$ to be a root $c$, but we have freedom to set $p$ to anything and let $q$ be a consequence. If we set $p$ just right, $pq-12304$ in the above will be $0$. Then we would have:
$$\begin{align}
p^3+q^3-2729252&=0&pq-12304=0\implies q=\frac{12304}{p}\\
p^3+\left(\frac{12304}{p}\right)^3-2729252&=0\\
p^6-2729252p^3+12304^3&=0\\
\end{align}$$
Now you can solve this "quadratic" equation for $p^3$. The two solutions are not real, that's OK. We can allow $p^3$ to be either one of them. We know $q=\frac{12304}{p}$ but it will work out that $q^3$ is then the other solution. So the two roots of $X^2-2729252X+12304^3$ are $p^3$ and $q^3$, and you can take their complex $3$rd roots to get $p$ and $q$.
From this, $c=p+q$. And then from this, $a=c+112$. In other words:
$$a=\sqrt[3]{1364626+6i\sqrt{13304183}}+\sqrt[3]{1364626-6i\sqrt{13304183}}+112$$
If we don't like having the complex numbers involved, we can use trig functions to express the same thing:
$$a=8\sqrt{769}\cos\left(\frac13\arctan\left(\frac{6\sqrt{13304183}}{1364626}\right)\right)+112$$

Approximate solutions
I derived the equation for $y$:
$$48y^4-120y^2+y+68=0.$$
From this equation, it is not difficult to see that $$y\approx\pm1.$$ But, then looking at your equation again, $x\approx\pm\sqrt2.$ So,
$$(x,y)\approx(\pm\sqrt2,\pm1).$$

It is easy to solve using the idea of quadratic residues and non-residues in number theory.  The first equation implies that $y$ is a square $\pmod{7}$ (since $y \equiv 4x^2 \pmod{7}$). The second equation implies that $x$ is a square $\pmod{5}$.  Using the Legendre symbol, we get, $(\frac{x}{5}) =1$ and $(\frac{y}{7}) = 1$; i.e., $x^{\frac{5-1}{2}} = x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, and $y^{\frac{7-1}{2}} = y^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$. Therefore, $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{5}$ and $y \equiv 1, 2 \ \rm{or} \ 4 \pmod{7}$.
Also, the two equations imply that $y - 7 \leq 0$ and $x+5 \geq 0$; thus $y \leq 7$ and $x \geq -5$. With these conditions, for each choice of $x$, we get a value for $y$ (in equation (1)), and for each choice of $y$, we get a value for $x$ (in equation (2)). The intersection of these two sets of solutions gives us the common set of solutions to the system.
Edit: Above method gives us only the integer solutions.  If one is interested in real solutions, the equation of degree 4 in $x$ can be converted into a cubic in $x$ (after a linear change of coordinate, and factoring out a linear term), and there is a known algebraic formula for solving cubic equations; only, two of the solutions may be complex (all three may not be real), and then one can determine $y$ from the solutions for $x$. In other words, there is an easy (known) way of solving it algebraically, instead of trying to solve it analytically.

What does quadratic residues have to do with finding real solutions? EG Did you consider when $ x = \pi$?

This is a method for finding integer solutions.  But I think we actually want real solutions.

Yes, you are right.  I took the system to be a system of Diophantine equations, but then I looked at the title again just now, and that is not what it says.

But @Calvin Lin, $x= \pi$ cannot be part of a solution, since $\pi$ is transcendental and does not satisfy an integer coefficient polynomial of any degree (let alone degree 4).

@AnuradhaNarasimhan  Sure, but that wasn't included in your considerations so you didn't eliminate transedntals previously. And even then, let's restrict to algebraic numbers, how do you know that (say) $ x = \sqrt{ 2 - \sqrt{2} } $ cannot be a solution?

@CalvinLin Yes I agree, I did not take real solutions into account.  I have now edited my answer post, to answer the question for reals.
